# Get product attribute reference - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, variables, attributes, prestashop

I need to get the product combination ean13 in module php file.
Using this i can get the product reference:

```
               $product = new 
               Product(Tools::getValue('id_product'));
               $varRef = $product->reference;
```

I have no ideea how to get the combination ean13, as it is an array of product.

```
{$product|@var_dump}}
'attributes' => 
  array (size=2)
   1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id_attribute' => string '1' (length=1)
      'id_attribute_group' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
      'group' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'reference' => string '' (length=0)
      'ean13' => string '' (length=0)
      'isbn' => string '' (length=0)
      'upc' => string '' (length=0)
```

Any quick solution? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works and will list the EAN 13 of each combination/variant for a given product:

```
$product = new Product((int)Tools::getValue('id_product'));
$id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
$combinations = $product->getAttributeCombinations((int)$id_lang, true);
foreach ($combinations as $c)
    p($c['ean13']);
```

Comment: Yes, it works just fine, thank you. How can i extract only the EAN for selected combination? The code you provided generates an array with all the product ean combinations, I need to register in a variable only the EAN for the combination that the user is seeing.

Comment: Try this instead: $ean13 = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT ean13 FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute WHERE id_product_attribute = '.(int)$id_product_attribute);

Comment: I added before that $id_product_attribute = Tools::getValue('id_product_attribute', null);  
It works just fine when I select a color attribute that refreshes the page, in order to load the new cover picture. Unfortunately when I select a new size attribute that has same cover pictures and nothing refreshes, I end up with a wrong ean13 code - for the default id_product_attribute.

Comment: I'd post a new, separate question for that, with a reproducible example